# Adding HTTP Legacy to Android Studio

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, httpurlconnection

Since Apache's HTTP library has been deprecated in favor of HttpURLConnection, i have been trying to add the legacy library to my project. I added the line

```
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

to build.gradle but the the HTTP methods cannot be resolved still. How do i get this to work?

These are the errors i am getting;

```
Error:(21, 59) error: cannot find symbol class List
Error:(21, 64) error: cannot find symbol class NameValuePair
Error:(23, 13) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(23, 48) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient
Error:(24, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpEntity
Error:(25, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpResponse
Error:(28, 17) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(28, 41) error: cannot find symbol class HttpPost
Error:(30, 44) error: cannot find symbol class UrlEncodedFormEntity
Error:(37, 42) error: cannot find symbol variable URLEncodedUtils
Error:(40, 17) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
Error:(40, 39) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet
Error:(48, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable EntityUtils`
```

The following is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.19.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.radioafrica.music"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

}
```

Comment: Please add your build.gradle to your post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, I have found that the library is actually included upon compile and packaging, but not shown in IDE.

As a workaround, you can remove the line

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

copy the file org.apache.http.legacy.jar from `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional` to `libs` folder in your project.

Reference on people reporting this problem

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=181474

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183668

Comment: I've updated to v1.3.1 but the problem still persists

Comment: Yes i have, several times in fact.

Comment: For those new to Android Studio, after you copy the file remember to choose "Add as library..."